# Regular Expression Not working in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I'm using the following expression.

> \W[A-C]{3}

The objective is to match 3 characters of anything between A and C that don't have any characters before them. So with input "ABC" it matches but "DABC" does not.

When i try this expression using various online regex tools (eg. http://gskinner.com/RegExr/), it works perfectly. When i try to use it in an asp.net RegularExpressionValidator or with the RegEx class, it never matches anything.

I've tried various different methods of not allowing a character before the match. eg.

```
[^\w] and [^a-zA-Z0-9]
```

all work in the online tools, but not in .net.

This test fails, but i'm not sure why?

```
[Test]
public void RegExWorks()
{
    var regex = new Regex("\\W[A-C]{3}");
    Match match = regex.Match("ABC");
    Assert.IsTrue(match.Success);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
^[A-C]{3}
```

It is simple, but seems to fit what you are asking, and I tested it in rubular.com and .NET

Comment: Yeah, your right it does work. But oddly enough it doesn't work when i try it on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ - i'm not sure which one of 3 the answers is the best? They all work

Comment: This is pretty standard reg ex, so I am not sure why it does not work there. If you go to the reg ex site, that is...

Answer (score 3):

Problem is that you *require* there to be a `\W` character. Use alteration to fix that, or a lookbehind to make sure there are no invalid characters.

Alteration:

```
(?:\W|^)[A-C]{3}
```

But I'd prefer a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!\w)[A-C]{3}
```

`\b` (as in gymbralls answer) is short for `(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)`, which in this case would just mean `(?<!\w)`, thus being equivalent.

Also, in C# you can use the `@` quoting so you don't have to double escape things, eg:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"(?<!\w)[A-C]{3}");
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider trying:

```
[Test]
public void RegExWorks()
{
   var regex = new Regex("\\b[A-C]{3}");
   Match match = regex.Match("ABC");
   Assert.IsTrue(match.Success); 
}
```

The `\\b` matches a word boundary, which means it will match "ABC" as well as " ABC" and "$ABC". Using `\\W` requires there to be a non-word character, which doesn't sound like it is what you want.

Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: sorry, i wasn't clear in the question, i wanted to ensure that no characters at all are before the match. I figured \w covered what i need. I think the negative lookbehind in the first answer gets me what i need. I wouldn't want it to match "$ABC".

Comment: @Robbie, the lookbehind in my answer *would* match that. Do you just want `^[A-C]{3}$`? What characters are allowed before `ABC`? If you only want to allow white space you could use `(?<!\S)[A-C]{3}`.

Comment: Yeah, i think the ^ is what i want... i dont want any chars before the match... it should only match things at the start of the input. I think its what Justin has said in his answer

Comment: Got it. Based on the question when you mentioned not wanting it to match 'DABC' it sounded like you wanted it to match those three characters only even if they had some other character before them. We might want to edit the question to make it clearer. Either way, I'm glad you found the solution you were looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the ambiguity in the question? I said "3 characters of anything between A and C that don't have any characters before them". Do you mean i should have said "anything" instead of "any characters"?

Comment: Kind of. The inclusion of the '\W' in your sample expression and the negation of word characters in your examples  [^\w] and [^a-zA-Z0-9] gave the impression that you were looking to only exclude specific characters prior to the three characters you wanted to match. It's not a huge deal. I'm thinking more along the along the lines of making the question more useful to people who come along later. I've probably spent more time wrangling over this than its worth.

Answer (score -1):

It is simple like "[A-C]{3}" this

Comment: that would not ensure matches were at the start of the input which is what i need.

Answer (score -1):

OK so you can try following Expression

"[A-C][A-C]{2}"